# How to focus something on next render with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm playing with hooks, and I'm trying to do the following:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const EditableField = () => {
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const toggleEditing = () => {
    setEditing(!isEditing);
    if (isEditing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {isExpanded && <input ref={inputRef} />}
      <button onClick={toggleEditing}>Edit</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is going to fail, because `current` is null, since the component haven't re-rendered yet, and the input field is not yet rendered (and therefore can't be focused yet).

What is the right way to do this? I can use the [`usePrevious`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) hook proposed in the React Hooks FAQ, but it seems like a painful workaround.

Is there a different way?

Comment: `isExpanded` is not defined. Is it a typo? I guess you meant `isEditing`?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to run a function after every render when `isEditing` changed. In this function you can check if `isEditing` is `true` and focus the input.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const EditableField = () => {
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const toggleEditing = () => {
    setEditing(!isEditing);
  };

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEditing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isEditing]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {isEditing && <input ref={inputRef} />}
      <button onClick={toggleEditing}>Edit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<EditableField />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` is generally preferred for DOM-related mutations & checks.

Comment: With Typescript, if an error says `Object is possibly 'null'.`, you have to type the ref `const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);` and use a condition `if (inputRef.current)`.

Comment: I had the same case scenario but I am not sure why if i do this logic in the `onClick` function it does not work even thought the `inputRef` is defined, works only in the `useEffect`?

Answer (score 8):

I know the accepted answer covers the requested element in the above question.

But as an additional note, if you are using functional components, make use of `React.forwardRef` to pass down the reference to child components. It might be
definitely useful for someone who refers to this question later on.

In a more cleaner way, you can write your child component which accept the `ref` as given below:

```
    const InputField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        return (
            <div className={props.wrapperClassName}>
                <input 
                   type={props.type}
                   placeholder={props.placeholder} 
                   className={props.className}
                   name={props.name}
                   id={props.id}
                   ref={ref}/>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Answer (score -3):

Or Simply use this component

```
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export const FocusedInput: FC<JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']> = (props) => {

    const inputRef = useRef<null | HTMLElement>(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current!.focus()
    }, [])
    return <input {...props} type="text" ref={inputRef as any} />
}
```

Comment: Why `inputRef as any`? Shouldn't it be properly typed without this cast ?

Comment: @VincentAUDIBERT Something that works is better than perfect. Don't you think so?

Comment: ^that response makes no sense and misusing typescript to typecast stuff to any is horrible practice that should not be recommended to anyone.