# React passing down hooks causes rerender and loss of focus on input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a parent component in which I initialize some piece of state, which I then pass down to the children components so that they can update that. However, when the update is triggered, the component tree is re-rendered and my inputs lose focus. Adding a `key` did not help.

```tsx
// App.tsx

export function App(props) {
  const useVal = useState("");

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          component={() => (
            <StartScreen
              useVal={useVal}
            />
          )}
        />
        // ...
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```tsx
// StartScreen.tsx

interface StartScreenProps {
  useVal: [string, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>];
}

function bindState<T>(
  [value, setState]: [T, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>]
) {
  return {
    value,
    onChange: ({ value }: { value: T }) => setState(value)
  }
}

export const StartScreen = (props: StartScreenProps) => {
  return (
    <form>
      <InputField
        key="myInput"
        {...bindState(props.useVal)}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

So, now when I start typing on my `InputField` (which is basically a wrapper on an `<input>`) on `StartScreen.tsx`, the input constantly loses focus as the component is totally re-rendered (I can see it in the DOM).

Comment: Maybe take a look at to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314857/how-to-focus-something-on-next-render-with-react-hooks). Also read about [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), hope this helps!

Comment: @norbitrial Unfortunately this doesn't help: I'm not looking for focusing an input field, but rather not to lose the focus on the element I'm already on because of a rerender. But thanks anyways!

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you are passing a function to the `Route`'s `component` prop (I assume you are using `react-router-dom`) :

From the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) :

> If you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would
> create a new component every render. This results in the existing
> component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just
> updating the existing component.

---

To solve this problem use the `render` prop :

```
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      render={() => (
        <StartScreen
          useVal={useVal}
        />
      )}
    />
```

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the
> undesired remounting explained above.